# Поиск адреса в яндекс картах. Callback по кнопке "найти" не работает на iphone

Tags: jquery, ios, yandex-maps-api, iphone

Есть стандартная форма для доставки заказа. Когда человек вводит адрес доставки (выбирает через сервис DaData), этот адрес подставляется в поле поиска яндекс карты и происходит имитация нажатия кнопки "найти", чтобы конструктор карт выдал в какой зоне доставки находится нужный адрес. От этой зоны зависит конечная цена.

имитация нажатия: `$('.ymaps-2-1-78-searchbox-button').click();`

Все работает на андроидах, винде и macbook, но не работает на iphone.

Также пробовал:
`$('.ymaps-2-1-78-searchbox-button').trigger('click');` и через стандартный JS.

Гугл выдает, что на айфонах нужно явно указывать кликабельный элемент как `<button>` или `<a>`, а в яндекс картах теги `<ymaps>`.

`cursor: pointer` тоже не помог.

Вопрос: как сделать имитацию клика по кнопке "найти" в яндекс картах, чтобы работало на iphone?

Либо, возможно, есть такой метод в API яндекс карт?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, может кому поможет:

```
  jQuery('#billing_address_1').suggestions({
token: token,
type: 'ADDRESS',
constraints: {
  locations: { city: 'Самара' },
},
/* Вызывается, когда пользователь выбирает одну из подсказок */
onSelect: function(suggestion) {
  searchControl.search(suggestion.value);
},
```

});

В DaData, при выборе подсказок, вставить наше предложение в яндекс форму.